# xctool build failure: Test bundle not found under `Debug-iphonesimulator`

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild, xctool

I'm experiencing failures while running xctool build. My command is as follows:

```
xctool clean build run-tests -only 'MyApp KIF Tests' -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace/ -scheme 'Debug'  -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6,OS=latest" -sdk iphonesimulator -reporter junit -reporter plain
```

The build fails with the following error:

```
Failed to query the list of test cases in the test bundle: Test bundle not found at: /Users/myusername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-blbvnisblktossbxwcmnxafkngts/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp KIF Tests.xctest
```

I looked up the `MyApp KIF Tests.xctest` in the path specified in the error message, and indeed I couldn't find that file. However, this file does exist under a different path:

```
/Users/myusername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-blbvnisblktossbxwcmnxafkngts/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp KIF Tests.xctest
```

The only difference between these two paths is that one is under `Debug-iphonesimulator`, and the other is under `Debug-iphoneos`.

I also noticed that under target -> Build Settings -> Build Locations -> Per-configuration Build Products Path -> Debug, the value is `$(BUILD_DIR)/$(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)`, which was evaluating to `build/OktaVerify.build/Debug-iphoneos`. So the first question is: **why does `$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)` evaluate to `Debug-iphoneos`? What config do I need to change to make it evaluate to `Debug-iphonesimulator` so that xctool can find it?**

Next, I hardcoded the value of `$(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)` to `Debug-iphonesimulator`, wishing to see it working. However, I got the same error. My second question is, **why does the xctest file appear under `Debug-iphoneos` folder even the build products path specifies `Debug-iphonesimulator`? What setting is specifying `Debug-iphoneos`?**

Environment is Xcode 7.2 and xctool version 0.2.8.

Comment: Is this Test target a UIAutomation Tests target?

Comment: @BandoKal it's a test target, but not UIAutomation. For now we are still using KIF for UI testing

Comment: @SeaJelly did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: @jungledev yes, in the end I removed "-sdk iphonesimulator" from the command above and it started working

Comment: You are able to answer your own question in the formal answer section below, accept your answer, which will allow you to get upvotes for your answer.  Thanks for the prompt reply!

Comment: Thanks @jungledev, I have moved the comment above to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by removing "-sdk iphonesimulator" from the xctool command. This way it'll automatically choose the appropriate sdk depending on the target type.